# How to use Azure Synapse Spark pool to write to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

is it possible to use Spark environment inside Azure Synapse to write data into Azure Cosmos DB using Gremlin API? We need to build graph db into Cosmos, but since we are already using Azure Synapse, we would like to avoid charge for another tool like Databricks.

Thank you.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use Spark environment inside Azure Synapse to write data into Azure Cosmos DB using Gremlin API.

> Azure Synapse Link is available for **Azure Cosmos DB SQL API** containers or for **Azure Cosmos DB API for Mongo DB** collections.

[Synapse Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/configure-synapse-link?toc=/azure/synapse-analytics/toc.json&bc=/azure/synapse-analytics/breadcrumb/toc.json) for Azure Cosmos DB is a cloud-native hybrid transactional and analytical processing (HTAP) capability that enables you to run near real-time analytics over operational data in Azure Cosmos DB. Synapse Link creates a tight seamless integration between Azure Cosmos DB and Azure Synapse Analytics.

Today (i.e. September 22nd, 2020), you can run Spark queries against the data in MongoDB collections, with no impact to OLTP workloads and no ETL. Beginning next month, you’ll also be able to use Synapse SQL serverless to run T-SQL queries and to build real-time BI dashboards using Power BI in Direct Query mode over this data.

[image]

**Reference:** [Support for Azure Cosmos DB API for Mongo DB in Azure Synapse Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/ignite-2020-new-serverless-and-analytics-capabilities-announced/#support-for-azure-cosmos-db-api-for-mongo-db-in-azure-synapse-link)